# MongoDB Kafka Source Connector throws java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue full when using copy.existing: true

Tags: apache-kafka, mongodb-kafka-connector

When importing data from mongodb to kafka using the connector, https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-kafka, it throws `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue full`.

I use the default setting of `copy.existing.queue.size`, which is 16000, and `copy.existing: true`. What value should I set? The collection size is 10G.

**Environment:**

```
mongo-kafka-connect: 1.0.0
Kafka: 2.4.0
Kafka-Connect: 2.4.0
MongoDB server: 3.6.14
mongodb-driver-sync: 3.12.1
```

**Stacktrace:**

`org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue full\n\tat com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.MongoCopyDataManager.poll(MongoCopyDataManager.java:95)\n\tat com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.MongoSourceTask.getNextDocument(MongoSourceTask.java:301)\n\tat com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.MongoSourceTask.poll(MongoSourceTask.java:154)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.poll(WorkerSourceTask.java:265)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:232)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)\n\tat java.base\/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base\/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base\/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base\/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base\/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue full\n\tat java.base\/java.util.AbstractQueue.add(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base\/java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.add(Unknown Source)\n\tat com.mongodb.client.internal.Java8ForEachHelper.forEach(Java8ForEachHelper.java:30)\n\tat com.mongodb.client.internal.Java8AggregateIterableImpl.forEach(Java8AggregateIterableImpl.java:54)\n\tat com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.MongoCopyDataManager.copyDataFrom(MongoCopyDataManager.java:123)\n\tat com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.MongoCopyDataManager.lambda$new$0(MongoCopyDataManager.java:87)\n\t... 5 more`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in 
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-kafka/commit/7e6bf97742f2ad75cde394d088823b86880cdf4e

and will be released after 1.0.0. So if anyone faces the same issue, please update the version to later than 1.0.0.